# Is it possible to sum values with 3 or more criteria across a variable number of sheets in an Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I'm not even looking for a solution as much as I am some guidance on how best to even begin tackling this. Thanks in advance for reading.

To start off with, I find it difficult to describe my goal with words, so I created a picture which I hope will make it clear when paired with my words:

[image]

I'll try and describe what I'm trying to do as simply as possible:

I have a resource forecasting sheet which lists employees, the projects they're working on, and then features a "calendar" where the employees' estimated hours per project are shown for specific date periods in each month. (In this case, the date periods are each week in a month, plus the last day in each month if it falls in between a week.)

Next, each project that has employees assigned to it has its own tab. These project tabs list the employees working on the specific project, and feature estimates and actuals of both billable and non-billable hours. In any case, the classification of billable or non-billable is irrelevant except to say that each employee may or may not be listed twice in each project sheet. Finally, one employee may have hours logged in multiple sheets, and each sheet features the same calendar view as the resource forecasting sheet. What I'd like to do in pseudo-code would be:

SUM the billable and non-billable estimated hours of all projects where:

1. The employee name is the same in any project tab as the resources sheet,
2. The project name in the resources sheet is the same as the name of the project tab,
3. The date range in the resourcing sheet matches the date range in any project tab

It would be amazing if I could do the majority of this stuff using formulas, but I imagine I'll need to use some vba as well, which I have a little experience with, but not much at all.

If anyone could take a look at the image I've posted and give me some ideas as to a.) whether this can even be done, b.) how to start to think about doing it logic-wise and c.) whether this can be done with formulas, vba or a combination of the two, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks again,
Steve

Comment: where is the data for these tables coming from?

Comment: At the moment, the majority of the data is being manually entered, although the ideal result is to have it as automated as possible.

In the left-most sheet, both columns A and B are manually entered.
In the right sheet, A, B and E are manually entered.  In the calendar on the right sheet, currently both Est and Act for each week are manually entered, although my hope is to have the actuals for each week come from a separate table while each Est column remains manual.

Comment: The goal is for the values in C through ... in the left sheet to be automatically populated by the summed Est. values from matching resources and project tabs in the right sheet. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide test workbook (i.e. using https://dropbox.com)

Comment: Sure thing! https://www.dropbox.com/s/360b1p1cqzunkfy/Resource%20Forecasting.xlsm

Comment: it looks like you can use the SUMIF function to do this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

Comment: @SteveK, do you need to sum only Est column? or Act column too?

Comment: @SteveK, do your data always be in the same rows on all sheets SOW #1, SOW #2? (i.g. 6-17 as in example workbook)

Comment: @simoco for the resource forecast, it's only estimates.  I'll have another utilization sheet which will sum billable Act and total effort (sum of billable + non-billable effort), but I figured I'd start small. The resource data in column A on the project sheets (SOW #1 - SOW #N) will be variable, because resources can be added or removed from these projects on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a lot of merged cells, I found the simpliest way is to use UDF:

```
Function getData(targetName As String, targetSheet As String, targetDate)
    Dim res As Double
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim names As Range       
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheet)
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        col = Application.Match(targetDate, .Range("4:4"), 0)
        If col = 0 Then
            getData = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set names = .Range(.Cells(4, "A"), .Cells(lastrow, "A"))

        For Each cell In names
            If cell = targetName Then
                res = res + cell.Offset(, col - 1)
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

    getData = res
End Function
```

I've changed formulas on your 4th row in each sheet (with dates that was stored as text). Now they are stored *dates* and has format "mmm-dd". It is more correct approach, because if you're using `=Text(date,"mmm-dd")` you could have two identical columns for different years which is uncorrect (i.e. `jan-11` for 2013 and `jan-11` for 2014).

One more thing: this line `res = res + cell.Offset(, col - 1)` gets EST column. If you need ACT column, use `res = res + cell.Offset(, col)`

P.S. if you'd like to use plain formulas - look into [INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx) function, but I don't suggest you to go this way, because your data structure and merged cells would make formulas very complex.

Here is [test workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijlx2rkxgh65mp2/Resource%20Forecasting.xlsm).

Comment: This is both incredible and incredibly helpful - thank you very, very much.